# Как скопировать весь контент из NSTextView в буфер обмена NSPasteboard?

Tags: cocoa, objective-c

У меня есть NSTextView в котором контент состоит из форматированного текста и картинок. Хочу реализовать метод который будет копировать все содержимое этого поля в буфер обмена.

Если выделить все и скопировать нажав КМД+С и вставить куда-то к примеру в Mail.app или Ворд то все нормально, вставляет с картинками.

Нашел на CocoaDev метод копирования RTF http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CopyRTFFromTextView5

Но в моем случае оно не работает. Ничего в результате не вставляет.

Как скопировать в буфер обмена весь контент из NSTextView вместе с текстом и картинками?

Comment: "Если выделить все и скопировать нажав КМД+С, ... то все нормально, вставляет с картинками"
Стоп, ну так вы ведь при этом и сохраняете все содержимое в буфер обмена. Или я не понял вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы не пробовали использовать тип контента не RTF, а RTFD (поддерживает вложения вроде изображений и пр.)? Попробуйте в приведенном вами примере заменить 
`[textStorage RTFFromRange...`  на `[textStorage RTFDFromRange..`  и 
`NSRTFPboardType` на `NSRTFDPboardType`.

И вот [еще одна тема](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/123016-nstextview-and-sound-movie-attachments.html) по этому вопросу ( ну, точнее не совсем по этому, но там есть пример кода копирования в RTFD)

Comment: ёлки-палки, я перепробовал все типы кроме этого :)
работет все отлично.
Спасибо!